# Cassandra node goes down

Tags: nullpointerexception, cassandra

Last night, my node.js API threw error

```
All host(s) tried for query failed.First host tried, 127.0.0.1:Host considered as DOWN.
```

As suggested in error, it looks like cassandra node was down, so i dig into cassandra logs and found that their is an exception thrown by cassandra, but i could not figure out when this error could have been thrown.

Cassandra logs

```
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:73] 2015-04-02 19:12:58,844 Memtable.java:370 - Completed flushing; nothing needed to be retained.  Commitlog position was ReplayPosition(segmentId=1427954898588, position=3473692)
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:60] 2015-04-02 19:18:28,208 CompactionManager.java:521 - No files to compact for user defined compaction
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:61] 2015-04-02 19:28:28,209 CompactionManager.java:521 - No files to compact for user defined compaction
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:62] 2015-04-02 19:38:17,782 CassandraDaemon.java:153 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:62,1,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CacheService$KeyCacheSerializer.serialize(CacheService.java:475) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CacheService$KeyCacheSerializer.serialize(CacheService.java:463) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache$Writer.saveCache(AutoSavingCache.java:236) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$11.run(CompactionManager.java:1089) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-04-02 19:38:22,991 ColumnFamilyStore.java:856 - Enqueuing flush of sstable_activity: 65753 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:74] 2015-04-02 19:38:22,992 Memtable.java:324 - Writing Memtable-sstable_activity@166239084(6642 serialized bytes, 2952 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:74] 2015-04-02 19:38:23,105 Memtable.java:363 - Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-208-Data.db (3897 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1427954898588, position=3589687)
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:63] 2015-04-02 19:38:23,106 CompactionTask.java:136 - Compacting [SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-205-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-207-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-208-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-206-Data.db')]
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:63] 2015-04-02 19:38:23,221 CompactionTask.java:252 - Compacted 4 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-209,].  15,482 bytes to 3,897 (~25% of original) in 113ms = 0.032889MB/s.  328 total partitions merged to 82.  Partition merge counts were {4:82, }
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:62] 2015-04-02 19:38:28,210 CompactionManager.java:521 - No files to compact for user defined compaction
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:64] 2015-04-02 19:48:28,213 CompactionManager.java:521 - No files to compact for user defined compaction
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:65] 2015-04-02 19:58:28,214 CompactionManager.java:521 - No files to compact for user defined compaction
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:66] 2015-04-02 20:08:28,215 CompactionManager.java:521 - No files to compact for user defined compaction
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:67] 2015-04-02 20:18:28,216 CompactionManager.java:521 - No files to compact for user defined compaction
INFO  [BatchlogTasks:1] 2015-04-02 20:19:58,913 ColumnFamilyStore.java:856 - Enqueuing flush of batchlog: 5848 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:75] 2015-04-02 20:19:58,914 Memtable.java:324 - Writing Memtable-batchlog@1542233641(4538 serialized bytes, 10 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:75] 2015-04-02 20:19:58,915 Memtable.java:370 - Completed flushing; nothing needed to be retained.  Commitlog position was ReplayPosition(segmentId=1427954898588, position=3789073)
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:68] 2015-04-02 20:28:28,217 CompactionManager.java:521 - No files to compact for user defined compaction
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-04-02 20:38:22,989 ColumnFamilyStore.java:856 - Enqueuing flush of compaction_history: 1214 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:76] 2015-04-02 20:38:22,990 Memtable.java:324 - Writing Memtable-compaction_history@1912511539(240 serialized bytes, 9 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-04-02 20:38:22,992 ColumnFamilyStore.java:856 - Enqueuing flush of sstable_activity: 65753 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:77] 2015-04-02 20:38:22,993 Memtable.java:324 - Writing Memtable-sstable_activity@1348219988(6642 serialized bytes, 2952 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:76] 2015-04-02 20:38:23,049 Memtable.java:363 - Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/system-compaction_history-ka-107-Data.db (250 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1427954898588, position=3841853)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:77] 2015-04-02 20:38:23,053 Memtable.java:363 - Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-210-Data.db (3916 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1427954898588, position=3841853)
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:69] 2015-04-02 20:38:28,217 CompactionManager.java:521 - No files to compact for user defined compaction
```

No logs are generated after this point, possibly node went down and server side apis start throwing error.

Comment: It's likely that this exception is not the cause of your node going down.  It's possible your node is considered down for some other reason.  Is there anything else in your logs on the nodejs side that could indicate why the node is being marked down from the driver perspective?

Comment: Till now, i could not find anything helpful from nodejs side logs. I have redeployed the app with lowering the log level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Cassandra 2.1.5, see [CASSANDRA-8067](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8067)

Comment: I just saw this, but i could not understand the fact that, if NPE occurred at 19:38 time, and last log available is of 20:38. Is it intentional from Cassandra side to wait for 1 hour (may be to try to recover from some failure) and then make this node down.

Comment: Also, this error has occurred in every 4 four hour. So this is something not random. I would like to know the cause for this as well.

Comment: cassandra 2.1.5 is not available yet although you can apply the patch to your version of cassandra and rebuild it.  The cause of the issue is a bug where cassandra tries to update the key cache for a table that no longer exists.